# IntlProvider not injecting ids on FormattedMessage

Tags: react-intl, formatjs, babel-plugin-react-intl

I'm following the [guide here](https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/message-extraction#automatic-id-generation) to setup automatic id generation for FormattedMessage components under the IntlProvider but it doesn't appear to be injecting the ids at run time since I'm receiving this error in the console.
[image]

```
 An `id` must be provided to format a message. You can either:
1. Configure your build toolchain with [babel-plugin-formatjs](https://formatjs.io/docs/tooling/babel-plugin)
or [@formatjs/ts-transformer](https://formatjs.io/docs/tooling/ts-transformer)
```

I started with a new react app from create-react-app and added react-intl from there and following the installation instructions on the formatjs.io site.

babel.config.json

```
{
    "plugins": [
      [
        "formatjs",
        {
            "idInterpolationPattern": "[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]",
            "ast": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-intl-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.18.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "babel-plugin-formatjs": "^10.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^6.3.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "extract": "formatjs extract src/**/*.ts* --ignore=**/*.d.ts --out-file lang/en-US.json --id-interpolation-pattern [sha512:contenthash:base64:6]",
    "compile": "formatjs compile lang/en-US.json --ast --out-file src/compiled-lang/en-US.json",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "plugins": [
      "formatjs"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "formatjs/no-offset": "error"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@formatjs/cli": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-formatjs": "^10.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-formatjs": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';


function App() {
  
   return (
    <div className="App">
      hello <FormattedMessage description="other part of hello world" defaultMessage='world'></FormattedMessage>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

en-US.json

```
{
  "Oup1TP": [
    {
      "type": 0,
      "value": "world"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can enable the [enforceId lint rule](https://formatjs.io/docs/tooling/linter/#enforce-id) and it's looking for the same Id that is loaded from the en-US.json file.

I've tried lots of variations of eslint rules, switched to the .babelrc file, changed up the hash. If I manually put in an id on the formatted message or put the id from the compiled file, the app works just fine.

My understanding is that the FormattedMessage components under the IntlProvider with this setup should have the Id injected when I run. I'm basing this off the documentation recommending against manually adding ids in favor of automatic generation and this [fallback logic specified in the documentation](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components#message-formatting-fallbacks).

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to switch off of react-scripts. You can use Vite, Craco or react-app-rewired. 
Vite sample: https://github.com/newnewz/react-intl-vite-test
React-app-rewired: https://github.com/newnewz/react-intl-test

Comment: Many thanks xzist , I used Craco eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in the way `create-react-app` is set up. All the tools come preconfigured. I don't think you can [just install](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/167) Babel plugins. You'd have to [`npm run eject`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject) to be able to use them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Using CRACO, create-react-app-rewired and vite all work fine out of the box. CRA doesn't seem to run Babel plugins.

I've made sample apps with Vite and Rewired that run by default with no extra setup.
https://github.com/newnewz/react-intl-vite-test
https://github.com/newnewz/react-intl-test